# PHP syntactic sugar: How to apply a function on a given input multiple times?

Tags: php, function, syntax, syntactic-sugar

From a database I am getting a text where the function `htmlentities()` was applied four times. Sample text:

> specials &amp;amp;amp; workshops

In order to decode this text I have to do the following:

```
$out = html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode(html_entity_decode("specials &amp;amp;amp;amp; workshops"))));
```

Result:

> specials & workshops

Is there a natural way in PHP to write this more efficient?

Comment: You would have to do it recursively.

Comment: I would say, it is just your preference. But keep it simple and create a function for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to do it recursively in such a way that I do not need to know how many entities to match.

```
$string = 'specials &amp;amp;amp;amp; workshops';
$entity = '/&amp;/';

function recurseHTMLDecode($str, $entity) {
    preg_match($entity, $str, $matches);
    echo count($matches);
    if(1 == count($matches)) {
        $str =  html_entity_decode($str); 
        $str = recurseHTMLDecode($str, $entity);
        return $str;
    } else {
        return $str;
    }

}

var_dump(recurseHTMLDecode($string, $entity));
```

This returns:

> 11110string(20) "specials & workshops"

Here is the [EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/afa784d649887f6b63b48207cc4f853f2ee3fbda)

This could be improved by adding a whitelist of entities to the function so you would not have to specify the entity when calling, just loop through the whitelist. This would solve the issue of having more than one entity in a string. It could be quite complex.

Comment: Good solution for the specific problem!

Answer (score 1):

Why not declare a function to do so?

```
$in = "specials &amp;amp;amp; workshops";

$decode = function($in) {
    foreach(range(1,4) as $x) $in = html_entity_decode($in); return $in; };

function decode($in) {
    foreach(range(1,4) as $x)
        $in = html_entity_decode($in);
    return $in;
}

// inline
$out = $decode($in);

// traditional
$out = decode($in);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think creating a function is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

According to the recursive idea of @JayBlanchard I have no created the following - really like it:

```
/**
 * Apply a function to a certain input multiple times.
 *
 * @param $input: The input variable:
 * @param callable $func: The function to call.
 * @param int $times: How often the function should be called. -1 for deep call (unknown number of calls required). CAUTION: If output always changes this results in an endless loop.
 * @return mixed
 */
function recapply($input,callable $func,int $times) {
    if($times > 1) {
        return recapply($func($input),$func,$times - 1);
    } else if($times == -1) {
        $res = $func($input);
        if($res === $input) {
            return $input;
        } else {
            return recapply($res,$func,-1);
        }
    }
    return $func($input);
}
```

Working example call:

```
echo recapply("specials &amp;amp;amp; workshops","html_entity_decode",4);
```

Comment: What if you don't know the number of times though?

Comment: @JayBlanchard: For the more general applicability I also extended my approach. However the endless recursion only works for a function which after some time always results in the same result, otherwise it causes an endless loop. Risky XD